# syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '=' ...icipant.username, participant );@output_buffer.safe_append='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view I have:

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>

<% if participant != current_user %>
  <%= participant.username, participant %>
<% end %>


<%= link_to conversation.subject, conversation %>
<%= conversation.updated_at.strftime("%a, %m/%e/%Y %I:%M %p") %>
<%= link_to "Move to Trash", {:controller => "conversations", :action => "trash", :id =>   conversation.id}, :title=> "Move to Trash", :method=>'post' %>
<% end %>
```

I get the error above but when I remove

```
<% if participant != current_user %>
  <%= participant.username, participant %>
<% end %>
```

I get no errors and the link works

What am I missing? I tried looking around online but I'm following the if syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you just need to split your statement, because <%= ... %> expects one return value and you are trying to provide two, just do something like:

```
<% if participant != current_user %>
  <%= participant.username %>, <%= participant %>
<% end %>
```

Of course participant and username must return some meaningful value. Hope it helps.